# Fetch DateTime column from mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

In mysql last reading TimeStamp is column of Datetime. I want to fetch the aggreagteUsage based on last reading timestamp.

last reading TimeStamp is in yyy-mm-dd hr:min:se format (Ex:2015-03-02 09:15:36)

```
sql = "select aggregateUsage  from sensorhourlyaggregates where sensorId=250   
and lastReadingTimestamp =?";
PreparedStatement prepStmt;
prepStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
Timestamp sbegin = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
prepStmt.setTimestamp(1, sbegin);   

Sbegin is in yyy-mm-dd hr:min:se.nanosec format (EX:2015-03-02 09:15:36.00)
```

i am not able to fetch the data since both formats differ. how to remove
   miliseconds from time stamp. I tried
    Clendar.clear(calendar.miliseconds) but i am unable to fetch

Comment: Why are you using equals? Do you want records for a specific date? If so you can use `Calendar` to create a date without time stamp. But since the column name suggests its a timestamp you will need to change the query as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your Time-stamp into Date, Following code may help You.

```
Timestamp sbegin = new Timestamp(/* Pass Timestamp from DB */);
Date date = new Date(sbegin.getTime());
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the date format, you are not getting any records because there wouldn't be any records in database that has exact timestamp that you are supplying in the query since you are using equal(=) in your query.

If you want the records for a specific date, you need to change the query(since column name suggests that its a timestamp)

```
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date dateWithoutTime = cal.getTime();`
```